# Calculating $\sum_{j=0}^{j_{\rm max}}\prod_{m=1}^k x_{i,j,m}$ for large lists

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, memory

I am struggling with the calculation of:

$\forall i\,,\sum_{j=0}^{j_{\rm max}}\prod_{m=1}^k x_{i,j,m}\,, \forall k\ge 1$

where $i\in(1,i_{\rm max})$, $i_{\rm max}$ can be up to $1000$ but usually around $3$, $k\in(1,k_{\rm max})$, $k_{\rm max}\sim 10^5$ and $j_{\rm max}\sim 20-100$. The result should have dimensions $\{i_{\rm max},k_{\rm max}\}$.

I tried two approaches but neither of which works for the dimensions mentioned above:

1. Memory very intensive:

   `x = RandomReal[{-2.0*10^6, 2.0*10^6}, {2, 16, 1000}];
   x2 = Map[Table[#[[1 ;; i]], {i, 1, Length@#}] &, x, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
   x4 = Apply[Times, x2, {3}]; // AbsoluteTiming
   ByteCount@x4`
2. CPU intensive (also it has an annoying feature that it produces a differently shaped list `{1000,2,16}`)

   `x = RandomReal[{-2.0*10^6, 2.0*10^6}, {2, 16, 1000}];
   x3 = Apply[Times, Map[Function[y, Take[y, #]], x, {2}], {2}] & /@Range[Dimensions[x][[3]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
   ByteCount@x3`

They both work as long as the dimensions are as shown. But I ultimately need this for much bigger lists, the max size of the list can be up to `{1000,20,100000}` and though it is very unlikely that I will end up with such a huge list, list of the dimensions `{3,20,100000}` are common.

Neither of the methods mentioned above are capable of doing the product itself for the sizes mentioned so I have not yet got to the summing part along the second index.

### Update

I found `FoldList`: specifically (not doing the sum yet): `Map[Rest[FoldList[Times, 1, #]] &, x, {2}]` and it has some extraordinary results. With:

```
x = RandomReal[{-2.0*10^6, 2.0*10^6}, {10, 20, 100000}];
ByteCount@x
```

I get

```
x8 = Map[Rest[FoldList[Times, 1, #]] &, x, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{12.4321, Null}
```

Can I still do it faster?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`ParallelMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelMap.html) and [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html).

```
ParallelMap[
 MapThread[Plus, #] &,
 ParallelMap[FoldList[Times, #] &, x, {2}],
 {1}]
```

The inner `ParallelMap` calcuates the products of the sublist in parallel.  The outer `ParallelMap` then calculates the sums in parallel.

Hope this helps.

---

Comparison using [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am having strange results with `ParallelMap`: `Map[FoldList[Times, #] &, x, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming` gives `{2.59738, Null}` while `ParallelMap[FoldList[Times, #] &, x, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming` results in `{73.3312, Null}`. I am on linux. Can you see the same behaviour?

Comment: @leosenko Yes. I get that as well. You should report to WRI.  However, when compared to the CPU intensive method in your post the `ParallelMap` above wins.  It is odd that the two statements in your comment don't reflect that.